# is there a coding way to check whether a color palette follows the color schemes of a color wheel like Analogous, monochromatic, triadic etc..?

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, color-theory, color-wheel

I am eager to build a system which tells whether my color palette follows any color schemes from the color wheel, i.e., monochromatic, analogous, complementary, split complementary, triadic, square, and rectangle (or tetradic).

I have been thinking about this problem since last few days but couldn't come up with something.

I don't have that much clues about it as to where to start, please if I can get some initial ideas as to how to proceed using python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no colour-theorist and will happily remove my suggestion if someone with knowledge/experience contributes something more professional.

I guess you want to convert to [HSL/HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) colourspace, which you can do with **ImageMagick** or **OpenCV** very simply.

- For monochromatic, you'd look at the Hue channel (angle) and see if all the Hues are within say 10-15 degrees of each other.
- For complementary, you'd be looking for 2 groups of Hue angles around 180 degrees apart.
- For triadic, 3 clusters of angles separated by around 120 degrees. And so on. I don't know the more exotic schemes.

You can get HSV with **OpenCV** like this:

```
import cv2

# Open image as BGR
im = cv2.imread(XXX)

# Convert to HSV
HSV = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Bear in mind that **OpenCV** Hue angles are half the conventional values so that the 0..360 range fits inside an unsigned 8-bit integer as 0..180 if dealing with 8-bit images. Range is the conventional 0..360 when dealing with floats.

---

Here is a little example with a colour wheel, where I split the image into Hue, Saturation and Value with **ImageMagick** and then lay out the channels beside each other with Hue on the left, Saturation in the centre and Value on the right:

```
magick colorwheel.png -colorspace HSV -separate +append separated.png
```

**Input Image**

[image]

**Separated Image**

[image]

Hopefully you can see that the **Hue** values go around the colour wheel in the left panel, that the **Saturation** decreases as you move away from the centre and that the **Value** increases as you move out radially.

You can hover a colour picker over, say, the green tones and see that they all have similar **Hue**. So, if you were looking for complementary colours. hover over the two and see if they are 180 degrees of **Hue** apart, for example.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, this approach gave me clarity as to start thinking in this direction.